# Trying to rewrite this using arrow syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions

I thought I could do this:

```
$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', e => {
        var self = $(e)
        self.data('before', self.html())
        return self
})
```

but it's saying: "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"

```js
$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', myfocus)

function myfocus() {
  var self = $(this)
  self.data('before', self.html())
  return self
}
```

```css
p {
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable>Click here to edit</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$(e.target)`;

In `myfocus` function,  `this` is a **reference** that refers to the **DOM** `element` that triggered the `event`.

In the jquery function, `this` refers to the `event` created, so you can access the `DOM` element using `event.target`.

`event.target` property returns the element that triggered the `event`.

```js
$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', (e) => {
        var self = $(e.target);
        self.data('before', self.html())
        return self;
})
```

```css
p {
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable>Click here to edit</p>
```

Comment: @PeterMader, yes, you're right. `pointer` is usually used in `c` and `c++` languages.